# Error when creatin SQL table. Eban classes

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.3

I try to create a `Transaction` SQL table, which contains two foreign key from two others tables : `User` and `Car`. 
**Car.java**

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Model{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id; 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_fk")
    public User user; 
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="car")
    public Transaction transaction; 
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;  
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user") // If we delete a user, all the object belongs to this user are deleted. 
    public List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    public Transaction transaction; 
}
```

**Transaction.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
public class Transaction extends Model{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id; 
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_fk")
    public User user; 
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_fk")
    public Car car; 
}
```

This is the generated `transactions` table script

```
create table transactions (
id                        integer not null,
user_fk                   integer,
car_fk                    integer,
from                      timestamp,
to                        timestamp,
availability              boolean,
constraint pk_transactions primary key (id))

alter table transactions add constraint fk_transactions_user_4 foreign key (user_fk) references user (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_transactions_user_4 on transactions (user_fk);
alter table transactions add constraint fk_transactions_car_5 foreign key (car_fk) references car (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_transactions_car_5 on transactions (car_fk);
```

And I got the following error:

> Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONS ( ID INTEGER
>   NOT NULL, USER_FK INTEGER, CAR_FK INTEGER, FROM[*] TIMESTAMP, TO
>   TIMESTAMP, AVAILABILITY BOOLEAN, CONSTRAINT PK_TRANSACTIONS PRIMARY
>   KEY (ID)) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement: create table
>   transactions ( id integer not null, user_fk integer, car_fk integer,
>   from timestamp, to timestamp, availability boolean, constraint
>   pk_transactions primary key (id)) [42001-175] [ERROR:42001,
>   SQLSTATE:42001], while trying to run this SQL script

What did I do wrong?

Comment: use backticks to avoid reserve words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONS ( 
ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
USER_FK INTEGER, 
CAR_FK INTEGER, 
FROM[*] TIMESTAMP, 
TO TIMESTAMP, 
AVAILABILITY BOOLEAN, 
CONSTRAINT PK_TRANSACTIONS PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

The error is the use of FROM as a column name. FROM is a reserved word and there is absolutely no reason to ever use a reserved word as the name of a column http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html. So just choose a name that is not a reserved word.

Comment: I thought transactions was the reserved name, I focused on this word. Than fot the help!

Comment: I would avoid a name like that as well, to easy for someone else to misread it later.